# Entity Framework Core Include Isn't Working Sporadically

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-2.0

In the query below EF Core doesn't set the included Shipment property even though it exists in all records. How can the included property always be included in the results?

```
List<Order> result = _context
    .Orders
    .Include(x => x.Shipment)
    .Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7))
    .ToList();
// Count below is greater than 0
// Foreign key exists on Order and Shipment
var ordersWithNoShippingInfo = result.Where(x => x.Shipment == null)
```

Comment: Does order also have a Shipment property that is set to `Virtual`?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible EF Core is hitting size limits with the data in the Included property. If the returned data isn't being updated, then **use .AsNoTracking()** to improve the query performance to help the "Included" properties get set with larger query results.

```
List<Order> result = _context
    .Orders
    .Include(x => x.Shipment)
    .Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Spent hours trying to work out why my includes stopped working after upgrading to .net core